# google Apps Script Export Issues

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm having an issue with Google Apps Script.  I've got a script that currently exports an entire column to individual txt files, however, I want to reuse this script but for only one cell.  The issue is that no matter what I change the getRange values to, it continues to export the entire column.  Below is the script:

```
function round01Quali() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg = sh.getRange(2, 2, 1, 2);
  var vs = rg.getValues().filter(r => r.every(Boolean));
  vs.forEach(r => DriveApp.getFolderById(deleteround01Quali('1m_-D9loocLQEJ_2AMWS1EAm3pJeFycpV', r[0])).createFile('starting-grid.svg', r[1]));
}
```

Can anyone pinpoint what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: Can you test: sh.getRange("A1").getValues(); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making a slight modification to your code and running on apps script to check the value being provided from one single cell, for example E1 should give me an IP:

```js
function round01Quali() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg = sh.getRange("E2").getValues();
  //var vs = rg.getValues().filter(r => r.every(Boolean));
  //vs.forEach(r => DriveApp.getFolderById(deleteround01Quali('1m_-D9loocLQEJ_2AMWS1EAm3pJeFycpV', r[0])).createFile('starting-grid.svg', r[1]));
  Logger.log (rg);
}
```

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CHn0kKE1lz4dzsKGeb7dDFkInkBDgG4xxrGLFv4dZGI/edit?usp=sharing) example with the IP the response from the log is:
[image]